# Eclipselink JPA support on wildfly 10.1

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, wildfly, jpa-2.1, wildfly-10

I have successfully ran eclipselink 2.6.2 on wildfly 10.0
But when I tried to migrate my application to wildfly 10.1 I got the following 
error.

> *org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **No [EntityType] was found for
>   the key class  in the Metamodel** - please verify that the [Entity]
>   class was referenced in persistence.xml using a specific
>   com.unilever.replenishment.model.entities.ReplItem
>   property or a global
>   false element.*

My persistence unit looks like the following (which works on wildfly 10.0)

```
<persistence-unit name="com.unilever_Replenishment_PU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>REPLENISHMENT_JNDI</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
</persistence-unit>
```

I am not sure if this is a bug in wildfly 10.1 , 
Any solution for this issue ?

Comment: How did you install eclipselink?

Comment: I have followed these steps which is the same for wildfly 10 as well --> http://vmutter.blogspot.com/2015/08/using-eclipselink-as-jpa-21.html

Comment: I think it changed a bit in WildFly 10 as jipijapa was moved back into WildFly instead of being a separate project. See https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/JPA+Reference+Guide#JPAReferenceGuide-UsingEclipseLink.

Comment: it works with wildfly 10.0 , but the same project with the same eclipselink configuration does not work in wildfly 10.1

Comment: @SamyOmar Any luck? How did you solve this for WildFly 10.1?

Comment: I switched to hibernate in wildfly 10.1,   and may be eclipselink will work with u as maybe i did something wrong in the configuration

Comment: Also try to use the latest version of eclipse link